# How can I get the GPS device data inside own customized server?

Tags: java, gps

I have configured a gps device with all the basic configuration settings. 
Also I have set the server ip to my windows server with port no. 7700 which have been done successfully.

In the server end I am using Java Socket to listen the port 7700

```
try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(7700)) {
        System.out.println("Server is listening on port 7700");
        int loop_counter = 1;
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("--- Refresh : "+loop_counter+" ---");
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("New client connected");

            InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

            OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(output, true);
            String text;
            String userInput;
            while ((userInput = reader.readLine()) != null){
                writer.println(userInput);
                writer.flush();
                //writer.close();
                System.out.println("echo: " + userInput);
            }
            //socket.close();
            loop_counter++;
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Server exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The output is something like this:

```
Server is listening on port 7700
--- Refresh : 1 ---
New client connected
echo: xx
echo: V‚01
Server exception: socket closed
java.net.SocketException: socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at com.nru.test.Server.main(Server.java:29)
```

Kindly can anybody help me getting the proper way to get the GPS device data inside server.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is our working Java-code for setting up a socket for the server connection:

```
public class SocketConnect {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    private Socket socket = null;
    private ObjectOutputStream sOutput;
    private boolean bindSocketPerformed = false;

    public boolean startSocket() {
        final int port = 4321;
        InetAddress addr = null;
        try {
            addr = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            LOG.error("SocketConnection: UnknownHostException     InetAddress.getByName ", e);
            shutdownSocket(serverSocket, socket);
            return false;
        }
        if (!bindSocketPerformed) {
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOG.info("SocketConnection: IOException new ServerSocket ", e);
                shutdownSocket(serverSocket, socket);
                return false;
            }
            try {
                serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                LOG.error("SocketConnection: IOException setReuseAddress/setSoTimeout ", e);
                shutdownSocket(serverSocket, socket);
                return false;
            }
            try {
                SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(addr, port);
                serverSocket.bind(socketAddress);
                bindSocketPerformed = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOG.error("SocketConnection: IOException bind ServerSocket ", e);
                shutdownSocket(serverSocket, socket);
                return false;
            }
        }
        try {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            LOG.info("SocketConnection: Server Accept done");
            LOG.info("Initializing with empty message");
            LOG.debug("Finished writing and closing the first object");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error("SocketConnection: IOException bind ServerSocket ", e);
            shutdownSocket(serverSocket, socket);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void shutdownSocket(ServerSocket serverSocket, Socket socket) {
        try {
            if (sOutput != null) {
                sOutput.close();
            }
            if (socket != null) {
                socket.close();
            }
            if (serverSocket != null) {
                serverSocket.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.info("SocketConnection: IOException socket.close ", e);
        }
    }

    public writeMsg(MySharedObject obj) {
        try {
            LOG.debug("Before socket write");
            sOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            sOutput.writeObject(obj);
            sOutput.flush();
            LOG.info("After socket write");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error("Error sending message [{}]", obj.toString());
        }
    }
    private void close() {
        // try to close the connection
        try {
            if (sOutput != null)
                sOutput.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.info("Close Input/output Streams exception", e);
        }
        try {
            if (socket != null)
            socket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.info("Close Input/output Socket exception", e);
        }
    }
}
```

We experimented with the Java-code to get it working seamlessly. As you can see, we set `serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true)`, before starting the actual connection.

You can substitute the default Inet address string "127.0.0.1" by any accessible address of your choice. Also the port number `4321` can be altered.

Comment: Thanks Flying Dutchman for your fast response, I have tested your code its fine but while reading the port it takes too long to execute whereas I assume the request is to come every 10 seconds interval

Comment: Nice to read that you have the Java code for the server-side socket connection working. The timing depends on the speed with which the client opens the socket connection.